# How to add a new row into a MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to create a new object via this function. But, this wouldn't work. The problem is that I'm not getting any error and there is no output message.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
public function create($obj){
        try{
            $requete=$this->bdd->bd->prepare('INSERT INTO fiche (mois, annee, nbFiches, statut, commentaire, intervenant0, charge0, tauxCharge0, intervenant1, charge1, tauxCharge1, intervenant2, charge2, tauxCharge2, intervenant3, charge3, tauxCharge3, intervenant4, charge4, tauxCharge4, intervenant5, charge5, tauxCharge5, intervenant6, charge6, tauxCharge6, intervenant7, charge7, tauxCharge7, intervenant8, charge8, tauxCharge8, intervenant9, charge9, tauxCharge9) VALUES (:mois, :annee, :nbFiches, :statut, :commentaire, :intervenant0, :charge0, :tauxCharge0, :intervenant1, :charge1, :tauxCharge1, :intervenant2, :charge2, :tauxCharge2, :intervenant3, :charge3, :tauxCharge3, :intervenant4, :charge4, :tauxCharge4, :intervenant5, :charge5, :tauxCharge5, :intervenant6, :charge6, :tauxCharge6, :intervenant7, :charge7, :tauxCharge7, :intervenant8, :charge8, :tauxCharge8, :intervenant9, :charge9, :tauxCharge9)');
            $requete->bindValue(':mois', $obj->getMois(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $requete->bindValue(':annee', $obj->getAnnee(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $requete->bindValue(':nbFiches', $obj->getNbFiches(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $requete->bindValue(':statut', $obj->getStatut(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $requete->bindValue(':commentaire', $obj->getCommentaire(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $requete->bindValue(':intervenant0', $obj->getIntervenant0(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $requete->bindValue(':charge0', $obj->getCharge0(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $requete->bindValue(':tauxCharge0', $obj->getTauxCharge0(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $requete->bindValue(':intervenant1', $obj->getIntervenant1(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $requete->bindValue(':charge1', $obj->getCharge1(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $requete->bindValue(':tauxCharge1', $obj->getTauxCharge1(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $requete->bindValue(':intervenant2', $obj->getIntervenant2(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $requete->bindValue(':charge2', $obj->getCharge2(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $requete->bindValue(':tauxCharge2', $obj->getTauxCharge2(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $requete->bindValue(':intervenant3', $obj->getIntervenant3(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $requete->bindValue(':charge3', $obj->getCharge3(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $requete->bindValue(':tauxCharge3', $obj->getTauxCharge3(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $requete->bindValue(':intervenant4', $obj->getIntervenant4(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $requete->bindValue(':charge4', $obj->getCharge4(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $requete->bindValue(':tauxCharge4', $obj->getTauxCharge4(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $requete->bindValue(':intervenant5', $obj->getIntervenant5(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $requete->bindValue(':charge5', $obj->getCharge5(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $requete->bindValue(':tauxCharge5', $obj->getTauxCharge5(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $requete->bindValue(':intervenant6', $obj->getIntervenant6(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $requete->bindValue(':charge6', $obj->getCharge6(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $requete->bindValue(':tauxCharge6', $obj->getTauxCharge6(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $requete->bindValue(':intervenant7', $obj->getIntervenant7(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $requete->bindValue(':charge7', $obj->getCharge7(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $requete->bindValue(':tauxCharge7', $obj->getTauxCharge7(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $requete->bindValue(':intervenant8', $obj->getIntervenant8(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $requete->bindValue(':charge8', $obj->getCharge8(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $requete->bindValue(':tauxCharge8', $obj->getTauxCharge8(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $requete->bindValue(':intervenant9', $obj->getIntervenant9(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $requete->bindValue(':charge9', $obj->getCharge9(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $requete->bindValue(':tauxCharge9', $obj->getTauxCharge9(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $requete->execute();
            //$nouveauobj = $this->bdd->bd->lastInsertId();
            $requete->CloseCursor();
        } catch (Exception $e){
                die('Erreur: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

How to fix this, please? What's wrong? Note that I'm using the same code to select and delete rows and it's working perfectly.

Comment: Please check [Errors and error handling](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php).

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario, thank you but how to autogenerate a primary key ?

Comment: [Using AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Comment: For very long lines, like your first line, [consider formatting them like this](http://pastie.org/private/mgedzeny6xuol0odme3sw) - not just here but in your editor too. This helps keep your code much more visible to you, and helps me easily see you could do with more normalisation (i.e. data needs to go in other tables). It's a matter of opinion, but I think a soft margin of 100 chars works quite well.